# How to distribute apps for own organization to their personal device?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-id, mobile-device-management

We are trying to publish an app for our own organization.

Initially we submitted to app store review. It got rejected, because app designed for specific organizations.

So we look the other options,

1. Apple business manager - it need managed apple id
2. Apple enterprise account - it also needs to manage apple id

My understanding, **managed apple id** means it belongs to organization, we can't use it with our private device. Is it right?

We want to install this to their private devices and private apple account. What's the best choice for this case?

Feel free to give your own suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: You could try ad-hoc or in-house distribution. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html) for more details.

Comment: @MrDeveloper thank you! will look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you mean by "Apple enterprise account" but there is the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/):

> The Apple Developer Enterprise Program allows large organizations to develop and deploy proprietary, internal-use apps to their employees. This program is for specific use cases that require private distribution directly to employees using secure internal systems or through a Mobile Device Management solution.

It's possible to develop and sign apps with this program, distribute them on an internal website and send a link to that website to your employees. They have to accept your organization as a trusted developer, but otherwise you don't have to manage Apple IDs or something like that.